# Save System.Windows.Media.Brush as image file to disk

Tags: wpf, d3dimage

I have D3DImage _di that use to draw a background of Wpf Border in the form of a Brush.
The Image is rendered fine but i want to save the Brush to png file on disk even if the Brush is not showed on the View.

I tried as below to save it to disk but all i got is black image:

```
            _receivedBrush =(Brush)new ImageBrush((ImageSource)_di)            
            RenderTargetBitmap bmpCopied = new RenderTargetBitmap(350, 174, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
            DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
            using (DrawingContext dc = dv.RenderOpen())
            {               
                dc.DrawRectangle(_receivedBrush, null, new Rect(new Point(), new Size(350, 174)));
            }
            bmpCopied.Render(dv);
            MemoryStream mse = new MemoryStream();
            BmpBitmapEncoder mem = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            mem.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmpCopied));
            mem.Save(mse);
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"g:\brush.png", mse.ToArray());
            mse.Close();
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score -1):

Try changing to PngBitmapEncoder or change the file extension to bmp.